# LibGDX - method isn't called

Tags: methods, libgdx, dispose

```
public abstract class Level implements Disposable {
    Game game;
    Stage stage;

    ...

    stage.addAction(sequence(delay(10), new Action() {
        @Override
        public boolean act(float delta) {
            dispose();
            System.out.println("here");
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
            return false;
        }
    }));

    ...

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        System.out.println("dispose called");
    }

    ...

}
```

In this piece of code, I want to call the Overridden dispose method. It says `here` in the command line as expected. However, it doesn't say `dispose called`. I am confused, how am I supposed to call dispose in this situation?

Or is there any easier way to do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: stage is disposable too. You've set the action on the stage, so could be the stage's dispose method is being called, instead of level's.

Comment: But when I press ctrl and click `dispose();` it goes to the overridden method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found it. Since it was an abstract class, I have extended new class to Level. It has its own dispose method and I haven't called `super.dispose()` so it was just calling an empty method.